# How to clear the contents of an array in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have declared a two dimensional array in the function library and associated it with a test. In action1 of the test, I tried to clear the array using "erase" statement.
**My code -**
In Function Library,

```
Dim strVerifyAry(25,6)
```

In action1,

```
erase strVerifyAry
```

Error message

```
Run Error - Type mismatch: 'Erase'
```

How to clear the contents of this array?

Comment: +1 for being reproduceable, yet obviously not easily explainable.

Comment: I had a similar problem and as a workaround set the array to zero as though it were an `int`. i.e. `strVerifyAry = 0`, then reset it as an array when I needed it again.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me in plain VBScript, so it's most likely an issue with whatever engine QTP uses for running VBScript code. You should be able to emulate the behavior of `Erase` for a 2-dimensional array like this:

```
Sub EraseArray(ByRef arr)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
      If IsObject(arr(i, j)) Then
        Set arr(i, j) = Nothing
      Else
        arr(i, j) = Empty
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Or like this, if you don't want to set fields containing objects to `Nothing`:

```
Sub EraseArray(ByRef arr)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
      arr(i, j) = Empty
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: QTP uses the "real" MS engine. There are, however, these and some other strange symptoms we've seen elsewhere which point into the direction that the library oviously has a global scope that is totally separated from the test script´s global scope in certain aspects (GetRef results are not always usable).

Answer (score 1):

I do not exactly understand why, but you can create a sub like

```
Public Sub DoErase (byRef Ary)
   Erase Ary
End Sub
```

in the library, and call it from within the action like this:

```
DoErase StrVerifyAry
```

and that works.

**Update:** No it doesn't. The array is successfully passed to `DoErase`, and the `DoErase` call works fine, but the test afterwards still can reference the array elements that `Erase` was supposed to be erasing.

If the test declares the array, it works fine (`Erase` erases the elements).

This is very strange and probably has to do with the quirky scopes in function libraries.

Please let us know if you ever find out what's going on here...

Comment: I have created a sub in the function library without the argument, because the array was declared in the function library itself. And it works fine. But still I could not figure out why it does not work when erased from the test.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for an entire afternoon so I wanted to post an answer for future reference.  I filled an array using the Split command and then needed to Erase it before the script looped back through the process again.  Nothing I tried would erase or clear the array and the next use of Split just appended to the previous array elements.
By trying the 'array=Nothing' loop above, I finally managed to generate a "This array is fixed or locked" error which I researched.  Turns out I had used the array in a 'For Each..Next' loop which locks the array so it can't be erased or cleared.  More info is available [HERE:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231012%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary collection rather than an array in some circumstances.  Then use `RemoveAll` when you want to clear it. That doesn't help when your array was created by a split function, or whatever, but it can help in other use cases.

```
Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
...
myDict.RemoveAll
```

Refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_dictionary.asp