# How to empty a multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vbscript, is-empty

I wrote an CSV import function. The CSV file gets seperated into columns and rows and is then saved into a multidimensional array.

At one point, I need to set the multidimensional array to `Empty`, because the following If-condition checks for `IsEmpty()`.

I already tried this:

```
aMultidimArray = Empty

aMultidimArray = Nothing

ReDim aMultidimArray(0,0)

Erase aMultidimArray
```

```
a = Split(sData, sDelimiter)
For Each x In a

    '*** Resize and write into multidimensional array
    ReDim Preserve aMultidimArray(iFirstDim, iSecondDim)
    aMultidimArray(i - 1,iSecondDim) = x
    If (i = iFirstDim + 1) Then
        i = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
'***Empty array here
???
'***
GetDataFromCSV = aMultidimArray
'**** other script
If IsEmpty(GetDataFromCSV) Then
    Do stuff
End If
```

The `IsEmpty(GetDataFromCSV)` should return true, but I cannot handle it.
It is NOT about clearing the array. It's about getting it uninitialized again. If this is even possible.

As a workaround (or maybe just a better solution) I just called `Exit function`. As a result the return value is `Empty`and the `IsEmpty`condition will return `True`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Where do the dimensions of the array come from? And why are you filling an array with values, and then emptying it right afterwards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the contents of an array in vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936423/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-array-in-vbscript)

Comment: It's just a snippet. It's not about writing data into the array. That all works fine. I just showed it to make clear how I write the data into the array. The question is only about getting it `Empty` again.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//5cs4befa%28v%3dvs.85%29):

> `IsEmpty` returns `True` if the variable is uninitialized, or is explicitly set to `Empty`; otherwise, it returns `False`. `False` is always returned if expression contains more than one variable.

Since your variable absolutely is initialized, even if you remove all values from the array, why would you expect `IsEmpty` to return anything but `False`?

Depending on what you actually want to achieve with your code you could check the dimensions of your array:

```
If UBound(GetDataFromCSV, 1) = -1 And UBound(GetDataFromCSV, 2) = -1 Then
    'array is a 0x0 array
End If
```

If your array is not zero-sized you probably need to iterate over all fields and check if those are empty.

If you think you need to reset a variable that was defined as an array to `Empty` I suspect you made a design error somewhere, so I would strongly recommend to go back and fix the design. However, if you absolutely must reset an array variable to `Empty` for some reason you should be able to do so like this:

```
ReDim a(2, 5)  'define variable as array
...
Dim a          're-define variable as regular variable; does not clear the value
a = Empty      'clear variable
```

Comment: Shouldn't `aMultidimArray = Empty` explicitly set it to `Empty` though?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I know the definition of the `IsEmpty`function. My problem is that I am working in a developer team and someone else is checking if the return of my import is `Empty`. I know how to clear the array, but I need to get it uninitialized again. If this is even possible.

Comment: @Lankymart Not if the variable was defined as an array. You'll get a type mismatch if you do `ReDim a(1,2) : a = Empty`.